# Created by , Updated by column cannot be null spring jpa error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am using spring boot and jpa and i want to save data in table. 
I have database table constraint not null on `createdBy`, `updatedBy`, `updationDate`, `creatingDate` columns.

I have similar DTO to entity and above mentioned audit fields are not in DTO but only in entity so meaning user don't send audit information.

On entity i am using this `@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)`.

`Problem is` when i try to update entity by `rep.save(entity)` i get this error `"Column 'CreatedBy' cannot be null`

My entity is using auditing entity listeners and it looks similar to this

```
    @Column(name = "isactive")
    private boolean active;
    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "createdby")
    private String createdBy;
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "creationdate")
    private Instant creationDate;
    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "lastupdateby")
    private String lastUpdateBy;
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "lastupdatedate")
    private Instant lastUpdateDate;
```

Note: If i try to create new object, it gets saved and worked fine and also audit information in database like created by updated by is also populated using auditing entity listener.
But when it try to update the same object i get the error of `createdBy` cannot be null, i am assuming these audit fields `createdBy` `updatedBy` .... should also be populated of filled by `auditEntityListener` the same way i create it by post request.

Comment: Add annotation called **@Nullable**, or **@Column** Attribute nullable=true

Comment: I think the issue here is that it should NOT be null @SwaritAgarwal

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas I guess error states **"Column 'CreatedBy' cannot be null**. If it is nullable then issue should rectify

Comment: Looks like you are setting `createdBy` to `null`. Don't do that.

Comment: that would be true if application allows guest users to create content. However most of the time you would not want to have orphan objects lying around in your database hence why, in this case, it would be either a bug in misconfigured principal or a bug in design allowing created by to be null.

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas Agree with point. CreatedBy and CreatedDate should never be null. **It may default it with some value as well for time being, like default=''SYSTEM''**

Comment: @JensSchauder in my case I want to set it to null after a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the updatable = false flag, e.g.

```
@Column(name = "createdby", updatable = false)
```

and

```
@Column(name = "creationdate", updatable = false)
```

that helped me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution, When we need to update the entity that is using AuditEntityListener 
i updated only the changed fields in entity comparing to DTO. 
MapStruct made it easy

`void updateEntity(@MappingTarget Entity target, DTO dto);`
now save the updated entity.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look how to use Audit Aware in [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/index.html#auditing.auditor-aware)